# Why is a Gamma family GLM needed to analyse this data?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution

Feigl & Zelen (Biometrics, 1965) gave data on the survival times in weeks of 33 patients suffering from a form of cancer. They also provided the values of two explanatory variables, white blood cell (wbc) counts in thousands, and a factor AG (ag) coded as 1 = positive and 2 = negative. The data are as follows.

[image]

Comment: Please clearly indicate that this is related to work for a subject (see the [help/on-topic] on homework-style questions. What makes you think a Gamma GLM is *necessary*?

Comment: @Glen_b Gamma GLM is suggested to me

Comment: Why ignore the first sentence in my comment above?

Comment: @Glen_b sorry I did not realise. Yes it is related to work for a university subject.

Comment: Did you read the link and follow what it said?

Answer (score 2):

This is **survival analysis** and this is a common approach. The type of data is time until event (in this case death from cancer) and the survival function can be modelled with gamma or Weibull or log-normal. Since the gamma distribution is a member of the exponential family, you could do this with a generalised linear model (GLM).

An introduction to the concept of survival analysis is given here, under chapter 3:

http://jgscott.github.io/SDS325H_Spring2015/files/logit_poisson_cox.pdf

**As for which distribution to choose**, sometimes a certain distribution is better justifiable than others. For example, in the simplest case if the events are Poisson distributed (i.e. occurring at a certain rate, independent of the last event), then the time between those events is exponentially distributed. In reality however, there are often unknown sources of variation contributing to the time until event. In that case, more flexible distributions can be used, with more parameters. The Weibull distribution for example, has two parameters and can therefore take on more different shapes than the exponential distribution. In fact, the exponential distribution is a special case of the Weibull. In turn, the generalized gamma distribution encompasses the Weibull, gamma, and exponential distributions.

So why the gamma distribution? Perhaps the authors provide some theoretical justification for this distribution, or perhaps this model outperformed other models in terms of AIC or ome other criterium. I don't know for certain, because the only paper from Feigl & Zelen (Biometrics, 1965) I could find is:
'Estimation of Exponential Survival Probabilities with Concomitant Information'
Which uses the exponential distribution, a special case of the gamma distribution.

Comment: I couldn't find an explanation of the use of Gammas in your reference: it merely mentions that they are used, but offers no indication why.

Comment: You are correct, I've updated my answer, but I could not find a specific reason to use gamma.

Comment: @whuber What are the 'general' reasons one would choose Gamma GLM?

Answer (score 2):

A Gamma GLM isn't *necessary* since there are numerous alternative possibilities.

If your question is "Why was Gamma GLM suggested?" ... you should ask the person suggesting. They might have had reasons other than reasons we might guess.

Times are necessarily positive and tend to be right skew, and often tend to have spread somewhat related to mean, so a Gamma GLM would at least be a feasible model to consider.

Comment: Well the question is asking me to explain as to why a Gamma GLM is needed to analyse the data.. I guess it is because that is topic that the question is linked to.

Comment: Note that when you ask a question that is directly related to your coursework (indeed any *homework*-style questions whether they're actually homework or not), you need to use the `self-study` tag (see the [help/on-topic[ under *Homework*. See also the `self-study` [tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). You need to show your own (serious) attempt (including what you did to research the issue) and ask specifically about where you got stuck, This would include things like explaining what your own notes or textbook had to say about when you would use Gamma GLMs  ...ctd

Comment: ctd... or what particular characteristics of the response would seem important. We aren't here to do your homework for you. If you're seen as honestly trying to do it yourself with a proper level of effort and [research](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) people will usually give good advice and helpful hints.